# Efficiently finding intersecting regions in two huge dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

I wrote a piece of code that finds common ID's in line[1] of two different files.My input file is huge (2 mln lines). If I split it into many small files it gives me more intersecting ID's, while if I throw the whole file to run, much less. I cannot figure out why, can you suggest me what is wrong and how to improve this code to avoid the problem?

```
fileA = open("file1.txt",'r')
fileB = open("file2.txt",'r')
output = open("result.txt",'w')

dictA = dict()
for line1 in fileA:
    listA = line1.split('\t')
    dictA[listA[1]] = listA

dictB = dict()
for line1 in fileB:
    listB = line1.split('\t')
    dictB[listB[1]] = listB

for key in dictB:
    if key in dictA:
        output.write(dictA[key][0]+'\t'+dictA[key][1]+'\t'+dictB[key][4]+'\t'+dictB[key][5]+'\t'+dictB[key][9]+'\t'+dictB[key][10])
```

My file1 is sorted by line[0] and has 0-15 lines,

```
contig17    GRMZM2G052619_P03  98 109 2 0 15 67 78.8 0 127 5 420 0 304 45
contig33    AT2G41790.1        98 420 2 0 21 23 78.8 1 127 5 420 2 607 67
contig98    GRMZM5G888620_P01  87 470 1 0 17 28 78.8 1 127 7 420 2 522 18  
contig102   GRMZM5G886789_P02  73 115 1 0 34 45 78.8 0 134 5 421 0 456 50  
contig123   AT3G57470.1        83 201 2 1 12 43 78.8 0 134 9 420 0 305 50
```

My file2 is not sorted and has 0-10 line,

```
GRMZM2G052619 GRMZM2G052619_P03 4 2345 GO:0043531 ADP binding "Interacting selectively and non-covalently with ADP" [GOC:jl] molecular_function PF07525  1        
GRMZM5G888620 GRMZM5G888620_P01 1 2367 GO:0011551 DNA binding "Any molecular function by which a gene product interacts selectively and non-covalently with DNA" [GOC:jl] molecular_function PF07589  4    
GRMZM5G886789 GRMZM5G886789_P02 1 4567 GO:0055516 ADP binding "Interacting selectively and non-covalently with ADP" [GOC:jl] molecular_function PF07526 0
```

My desired output,

```
contig17    GRMZM2G052619_P03  GO:0043531 ADP binding molecular_function PF07525
contig98    GRMZM5G888620_P01  GO:0011551 DNA binding molecular_function PF07589 
contig102   GRMZM5G886789_P02  GO:0055516 ADP binding molecular_function PF07526
```

Comment: It is hard to tell from your question what you want. Try looking at `set`

Comment: If the files are _huge_, you may want to use `grep` instead.

Comment: @devnull, would you mind to give more detailed answer, an example may be? I am not common with grep since I don't use it apart from counting number of lines in my file...

Comment: @user3224522 `grep` wouldn't suffice here, I didn't observe the output contains columns from both files.  You could use `join` but the input isn't sorted: `join -j 2 -o 1.1 2.2 2.3 file1 file2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding common ID's (intersection) in two dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385685/finding-common-ids-intersection-in-two-dictionaries)

Comment: @user3224522 You are asking the same question second time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385685/finding-common-ids-intersection-in-two-dictionaries Do not do that.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky that is my question, I changed the question, since some users complained that a new question should be self-contained I had to re-write the whole context.

Comment: If the input data is tab delimited, consider using the `csv` python module.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say for file 2 *I give only line[1]* but then I see three lines. The same with file1 there are 6 lines not 2 as you say. Which is the real format of the data?
What I think you don't parser correctly the files, that's why you lost ID when comparing the two methods.

Comment: my line[0] corresponds to column 1, not the row, line[1] corresponds to column 2. Could you suggest me how to parse better my files, in order not to lose ID's? thanks

Comment: Could you post 2 entries of your files, or a representative (and short  ) sample to work with? Then I could manage to think how to parse it. Another option could be that the file is too big to be loaded like this, but I work with ~300k lines and I never had a problem parsing.

Comment: I updated my input files above.. if I split 2 mln lined file to several files containing 300000 lines and several files containing 100000 lines I get different unique ID's...so I dont know how much should I split to get a right output

Comment: Rereading again your comment you say *unique ID*, but in the code you search for the **common** ID, so you should compare *all* the pieces of file1 against file_2 and then you should get the same.

Comment: sorry for confusion, I find unique ID's using a separate code, here I am interested in common ID's only. I am trying to understand your code and the one written using pandas (I am not v.familiar with it) I am also trying to use csv module here as it seems to be clearer for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend you to use PANDAS to cope with this kind of problem.

for proof that can be simply done with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd  #install this, and read de docs
from StringIO import StringIO #You dont need this

#simulating a reading the file 
first_file = """contig17 GRMZM2G052619_P03 x
contig33 AT2G41790.1 x
contig98 GRMZM5G888620_P01 x
contig102 GRMZM5G886789_P02 x
contig123 AT3G57470.1 x"""

#simulating reading the second file
second_file = """y GRMZM2G052619_P03 y
y GRMZM5G888620_P01 y
y GRMZM5G886789_P02 y"""

#here is how you open the files. Instead using StringIO
#you will simply the file path. Give the correct separator
#sep="\t" (for tabular data). Here im using a space.
#In name, put some relevant names for your columns
f_df = pd.read_table(StringIO(first_file), 
                     header=None, 
                     sep=" ", 
                     names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s_df = pd.read_table(StringIO(second_file), 
                     header=None, 
                     sep=" ", 
                     names=['d', 'e', 'f'])
#this is the hard bit. Here I am using  a bit of my experience with pandas
#Basicly it select the rows in the second data frame, which "isin"
#in the second columns for each data frames. 
my_df = s_df[s_df.e.isin(f_df.b)]
```

Output:
Out[180]:

```
    d   e                   f
0   y   GRMZM2G052619_P03   y
1   y   GRMZM5G888620_P01   y
2   y   GRMZM5G886789_P02   y
#you can save this with:
my_df.to_csv("result.txt", sep="\t")
```

chers!

Comment: OBS: pandas worth the installation. It able to easily open huge files with a lot of control, in a blink of the eye.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost the same but within a function.

```
#Creates a function to do the reading for each file
def read_store(file_, dictio_): 
    """Given a file name and a dictionary stores the values
    of the file in a dictionary by its value on the column provided."""
    import re 
    with open(file_,'r') as file_0:
        lines_file_0 = fileA.readlines()
    for line in lines_file_0:
        ID = re.findall("^.+\s+(\w+)", line) 
    #I couldn't check it but it should match whatever is after a separate
    # character that has letters, numbers or underscore
        dictio_[ID] = line
```

To use do:

```
file1 = {}
read_store("file1.txt", file1)
```

And then compare it normally as you do, but I would to use `\s` instead of `\t` to split. Even though it will split also between words, but that is easy to rejoin with `" ".join(DictA[1:5])`